# insert character into string in SQL table

Tags: sql, date, substring

I have a column of dates set out like '20180211'. I want to seperate out the year, month and day by adding a '-' between them and then convert to a date

```
select column,
        substring([column],1,4)+ '-' +
        substring([column],5,6)+ '-' +
        substring([column],7,8) as newcol1

FROM table
```

testing out the above code returns '2018-0521 -21'

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

thanks!

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `substring()` is (usually, please tag your dbms) length, not position. But why are you not converting to a date directly (`SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '20180211')`)?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2):

Your code must be change as

```
select 
        substring('20180211',1,4)+ '-' +
        substring('20180211',5,2)+ '-' +
        substring('20180211',7,2) as newcol1
```

else you can use this code

```
select convert(DATE,'20180211',121)
```

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of the substring function is the length you want to take. You were taking 6 characters for the month instead of 2, so it was returning `0521` instead of `05`.

```
select column,
        substring([column],1,4)+ '-' +
        substring([column],5,2)+ '-' +
        substring([column],7,2) as newcol1

FROM table
```

Whenever you have doubts, you can always split your expressions and test them separately.

```
select column,
        substring([column],1,4) as yearTest,
        substring([column],5,2) as monthTest,
        substring([column],5,6) as monthTest2,
        substring([column],7,2) as dayTest,
        substring([column],7,8) as dayTest2

FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

substring function has 3 parameters

```
SUBSTRING (str, position, [length])
```

Query should be like:

```
  select 
      substring('20180211',1,4) || '-' ||
      substring('20180211',5,2)|| '-' ||
      substring('20180211',7,2) as newcol1
```

The result will be '2018-02-11'

Date convertation dependents on your database.

PostgresSQL - `to_date(text, text)` 
Example: `to_date('05 Dec 2000', 'DD Mon YYYY')` in your case:

```
select 
        to_date(substring('20180211',1,4) || '-' ||
        substring('20180211',5,2)|| '-' ||
        substring('20180211',7,2),'yyyy-mm-dd') as newcol1
```

If you want only convert string to date, you could use mask 'yyyymmdd':

```
select to_date('20180211','yyyymmdd') as newcol1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT column, FORMAT(column,'yyyy-MM-dd') as newcol1
  FROM table
```